# ggplot2 theme with no axes or grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot with no information beyond the data. No axes; no grid; no title; just the plot.

But I keep getting extra margins and padding that I can't remove.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

theme_bare <- theme(
  axis.line = element_blank(), 
  axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
  axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
  axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
  #axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "lines"), # Error 
  axis.ticks.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"), 
  legend.position = "none", 
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"), 
  panel.border = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
  panel.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"), 
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "blue"),
  plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines")
)

ggplot() + 
  geom_area (data=economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy), linetype=0) +
  theme_bare
```

Produces this image: [image: plot]

What I want is this: [image: plot ideal]

I can't figure out how to get rid of the blue and make the dark gray flush with the edges.

Could any one offer some advice?

Comment: For the second part, you'll want to add `scale_*_*(expand = c(0,0))` for each axis.

Comment: @joran: SO I tried adding `+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`, but it says `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` whether I use continuous or discrete.

Comment: As a heads up, setting Date to numeric and applying the two `scale_*_*(expand = c(0,0))` functions removes the grey on the outside of the graph, but does nothing for the blue.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is the way to plot only the panel region:

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_area (data=economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy), linetype=0) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(line = element_blank(),
        text = element_blank(),
        title = element_blank())

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
ge <- subset(gt$layout, name == "panel")

grid.draw(gt[ge$t:ge$b, ge$l:ge$r])
```

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Out of curiosity, what is the best place to find info on some of these less-documented ggplot functions?

Comment: Does `line = element_blank()` really needs to go twice? :-/

Comment: a bit more concise, `grid::grid.draw(gtable::gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(p), "panel"))`

Answer (score 32):

From [`ggplot2_2.0.0`](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/) you can use `theme_void`:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_area(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy), linetype = 0) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: there's still some space around the plot

Comment: @baptiste Thanks for pointing this out. I was focusing on the "_No axes; no grid; no title;_" part of the question.

Comment: A minor note, this approach doesn't seem to work with `ggtext::element_markdown()` (it causes the html not to render, so instead you get raw html as text overlaid on the image)

Answer (score 10):

try

```
last_plot() + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.001, "mm")) + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

you may want to file a bug for the 0 tick length.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to remove the grid in theme_bw(), you can use:

```
+ theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```