# Remove white space (i.e., margins) ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, pie-chart, margins

I'm trying to plot a pie chart using `GGPLOT2` in R. I want to do this in such a way as to omit the extra margin space.

What I'm doing is similar to what sharoz did in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313285/ggplot2-theme-with-no-axes-or-grid/14317203#14317203) except I want to include a legend.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(x=factor(0),fill=factor(LABELS),weight=VALUES)) +
   geom_bar(width=1) +
   coord_polar(theta='y') +
   guides(fill=guide_legend(title='LEGEND'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the extra white space above and below the figure, the easiest solution is just to tweak the size of the graphics device. Here is aspect ratio is the key. If the aspect ratio of the graphics device matches that of the plot, you get rid of a lot of the whitespace.

What I use to save the plot is `ggsave`, in code:

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(x=factor(0),fill=factor(LABELS),weight=VALUES)) +
   geom_bar(width=1) +
   coord_polar(theta='y') +
   guides(fill=guide_legend(title='LEGEND')) 
ggsave("plot.png", width = 10, height = 5)
```

Just play around with `width` and `height` in `ggsave` until you are happy with the result.

Comment: I totally forgot about `ggsave()`! I kept not getting what I wanted with `ggplot()` under `pdf()` and `dev.off()`.

Comment: `ggsave` uses `pdf` under the hood, so the trick with `width` and `height` should also work with that.