# R ggplot, remove white margins in ggsave/ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

How can I remove the white margins in ggsave?

My question is exactly the same as [Remove white space (i.e., margins) ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16369708/1568919). However, the answer there isn't ideal for me. Instead of trial and error for a fixed but unknown aspect ratio, I would like to give `ggsave` a `height` and `weight` and want my plot (ie top of title to bottom of x-label) to automatically expand to that configuration without white margin.

[How can I remove the strange white margin around my .png (plotted with r, ggplot)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16441690/1568919) gives a way to make the margin transparent, but they are still there and the plot is smaller than `height` and `width` I set in the saved file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Found the answer from [Remove Plot Margins in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17786197/1568919)

```
theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))
```

does the job

Comment: When the aspect ratio is changed with e.g. `theme(aspect.ratio=9/16)` this will not work.

Comment: Unsure why this answer was accepted.  This merely removes the margin such that the axis labels,chart title, and panel are all have 0 margin.  The white bordering will still be printed with ggsave.

Comment: @JaBe, any tips on how to make it work with theme(aspect.ratio=...)? Been looking for this for days.

Answer (score 9):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440180/2678563) linking to [this blog post](https://www.pmassicotte.com/post/removing-borders-around-ggplot2-graphs/) there is a solution which also works for different aspect ratios. You can crop the image on your hard drive, independently of OS:

```
knitr::plot_crop()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Unix or Mac OS, another option when the various margin options aren't trimming enough is to use the `pdfcrop` command available within Unix through `R`'s ability to invoke system commands:

```
# after saving image, run pdfcrop 
system2(command = "pdfcrop", 
        args    = c("name_or_path_of_file_before_crop.pdf", 
                    "name_or_path_of_file_after_crop.pdf") 
        )
```

For more, see: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crop-r-figures/

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't do what I need, but pdfcrop does. Thanks!

Comment: `pdfcrop` does not exist in macOS UNIX (Monterey, v12.2.1).

Comment: Just tested pdfcrop on MacOS Monterey v12.1 (21C52) in Terminal and from R and it worked fine. Seems unlikely a fairly standard utility would get dropped from Unix.

Answer (score 1):

If pdf and `pdfcrop` aren't your thing, for example you work in png with a png logo - then see my answer here: [How to save a ggplot2 graphic with the proper aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089928/how-to-save-a-ggplot2-graphic-with-the-proper-aspect-ratio/61544215#61544215)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a command like this after `ggsave`:

```
system("/usr/local/bin/mogrify -trim -border 8 -bordercolor white output.png")
```

`-trim` removes an existing margin and `-border 8 -bordercolor white` adds a small 8px margin around the plot.

For a plot that had a gray background, a few white pixels were left around the edges of the plot, so I used the `-shave` option to remove a few extra pixels:

```
system("/usr/local/bin/mogrify -trim -shave 4x4 output.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

The sneaky little devil is the axis ticks length, alongside the plot margin you found in your own [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35358698/5009249).

You didn't provide an example, so here is one of my own.

- The problem appears, at least for me, when axis title and text are hidden, so I've set those in the theme.
- I've set the plot background to yellow so that the problem is highlighted

I've set the plot background to yellow so that the problem is highlighted:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = rnorm(10))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "yellow"))

ggsave(plot, filename = "example.png", width = 1, height = 1)
```

[image]

Removing the plot margins goes most of the way:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "yellow"),
    plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0))

ggsave(plot, filename = "example.png", width = 1, height = 1)
```

[image]

To finish the job, we need to set the axis tick length to zero (even though the ticks are already set to blank!)

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "yellow"),
    plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image]